# When a recipe calls for brown sugar, could I use white sugar instead?

Tags: sugar, brown-sugar

I don't really use brown sugar that often and I would like to know, if I am baking a recipe that calls for a cup of brown sugar, could I use white sugar instead? If not, why? Do they not "bake" the same?

Thank you!

Comment: Brown sugar keeps indefinitely if kept dry, so if you use it infrequently, why wouldn't you keep it in?

Answer (score 3):

Yes!

Brown sugar is nothing more than white granular sugar plus molasses. That's it!

1 Tbsp molasses per cup of granular sugar = light brown sugar and 2 Tbsp molasses for dark brown sugar. There is no need to waste your money buying either, or worse, both.

Omitting the molasses and just using plain white sugar in a recipe will however change the taste somewhat in the finished product. You'll need to experiment to determine if that flavor change is acceptable to you and those you cook for.

Comment: There will be some affect on texture as well as taste. Cookies, for example, will spread less with more white sugar and less brown.